# Hardware Device that splits a T1 line to 24 TTY Modems?

Tags: modem, tty, t1

I have ZERO experience with T1, so I'm having trouble using my usual means of research here. My boss told me there is a type of device that can split a T1 Line into 24 separate TTY Modems.

The research I have done so far says that there are 24 8-bit channels that make up a T1 line, so it all makes sense.

What is the technical term for this type of device, and where might one find one? Do I need this 'splitter' device as well as 24 modems? What types of modems would I need? Does each modem have a separate phone number - and if so how does it distribute each number to the modems? AHH!! So many questions, I hope I explained it all in a way that makes sense.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you really want to have 24 dialup modems? Or are you trying to make 24 outbound calls at once? Is this data, or fax, or ??

Comment: Yes, I really want 24 dialup modems. The company for whom I work has devices at sites where dialup is the only means of connections, and those devices must dial-in to our office, hence the need for the modems. 

AFAIK, no voice, just data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the hardware I need to do this:

http://www.dialogic.com/products/tdm_boards/media_processing/Diva_T1_PRI_24M.htm

Answer (score 1):

A T-1 is made of 23 data channels and 1 signaling channel. The Telco is responsible for assigning POTS numbers to each channel if requested. The device connected to the computer is called a [**PRI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_rate_interface) (Primary Rate Interface). Big networking companies such as 3Com sell them.